# Groovy (File IO): find all files and return all files - the Groovy way

Tags: file, file-io, groovy

Ok, this should be easy...

I'm new to groovy and I'm looking to implement the following logic:

```
def testFiles = findAllTestFiles();
```

So far, I've come up with the code below which successfully prints all files names.  However, instead of printing, I just need to put them into a collection.  Of course, I could do this the old java way: just instantiate a collection, add all the elements and return it.  However, that wouldn't teach me anything.

So how do you do this the cool, "Groovy" way?

```
static File[] findAllTestFiles() {
    def directory = new File("src/test/java");
    def closure = {File f -> if(f.name =~ /Test\.java$/) println f }
    directory.eachFileRecurse FileType.FILES, closure
    return null;
}
```

I'm looking to implement *findAlltestFiles()* in Groovy using as little code as possible while still being readable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd try to avoid building the collection entirely.  Using closures, you can separate the logic to select the files from what you actually want to do with them, like so:

```
import groovy.io.FileType

def withEachTestFile(Closure closure) {
    new File("src/test/java").eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) {
        if (it.name =~ /Test\.java$/) {
            closure.call(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Then if you want to do something on the test files, you can do it directly without building up a list in memory:

```
withEachTestFile() { println it }
```

or if you really want the list, you can easily generate it, using whatever collection makes sense:

```
def files = []
withEachTestFile() { files << it }
```

Comment: I feel that I really need the list of files but I'm probably wrong (since this is my first Groovy class, ever).  I will consider your first suggestion more thoroughly--it seems like a **great** insight.  I'm going to have to play with it to fully understand what you're saying and how to apply it--this is a completely different way of thinking of things! I like it... groovy is growing on me, fast.

Comment: I've re-written my entire script, trying to design with *closures* in mind. At times, it still hurts my head a little to think about it, deeply. But I'm sold on Groovy so I'll get a few books and start mastering this new approach. I'm excited to learn how to use Groovy Console... thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10):

A newer, standard and more generic way to traverse a directory which supports multiple closure callbacks is [`traverse`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#traverse%28java.util.Map,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29).

```
import static groovy.io.FileType.FILES
...
def files = [] 
new File("src/test/java").traverse(type: FILES, nameFilter: ~/Test\.java$/) {
    files << it    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

something like this should work

```
def files = []
new File("src/test/java").eachFileRecurse(FILES) {
    if(it.name =~ /Test\.java$/)) {
        println f
        files << f
    }
}
```

or i think modifying your code like this

```
static File[] findAllTestFiles() {
    def files = []
    def directory = new File("src/test/java");
    def closure = {File f -> if(f.name =~ /Test\.java$/) {println f; files << f} }
    directory.eachFileRecurse FileType.FILES, closure
    return files;
}
```

Comment: thanks! your answer was to the point and very helpful. I wish I could also award you points for the correct answer! Thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 2):

The following is untested, but the findAll method should help make your code very concise:

```
List<File> files = new File("src/test/java").listFiles().findAll { it.name =~ /Test\.java$/ }
```