# List all Java packages in SourceSet with Gradle, before compilation

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

Inside a `build.gradle` file, what's the most concise way to get a list of all packages in a `SourceSet`?

I can get it by parsing each source file, as below —

```scala
def sourceSet = project.sourceSets.findByName('test')
def pattern = Pattern.compile('package (\\S+);')
def packages = []
sourceSet.allSource.each {
  for (def scan = new Scanner(it); scan.hasNext();) {
    def matcher = scan.nextLine() =~ pattern
    if (matcher.matches()) {
      packages << matcher[0][1]
      break
    }
  }
}
packages.unique(true)

// allows, e.g.
packages.each { println it }
```

— but it seems as though there ought to be a better way.

---

**Edited to add:** I need this information in order to pass additional arguments to the JVM at compile time, so I need to get it from the source, before compilation.

Comment: if it's before compilation, then the only way is to parse.

Answer (score 0):

I made some searchs and did not found a perfect clean solution.

But here is one based on `java` files, using the path to resolve the package. Not need to use `allSource` as only `java` files are contained in a package.

This solution avoids reading all files.

```
def sourceSet = project.sourceSets.findByName('main').java
def packages = sourceSet
.filter{ it.path.endsWith('.java') }
.collect{ it.getParentFile().path
    .substring(sourceSet.srcDirs[0].path.length()+1)
    .replace('/', '.') }
.unique()

packages.each { println it }
```

Comment: This is not entirely correct. You can have resource files like properties or images in a `sourceSet` as well. Though it's unclear if the OP in interested in these files too.

Comment: *List all Java packages*, it implies the scope is java files

Comment: @DavidMoles Does this answer OK for you, or do you need additional help?

Comment: @Bsquare I don't think it's much of an improvement on the original, and there are better generic Groovy file-recursion solutions, e.g. in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4055339/27358). I was hoping for something making better leverage of the Gradle API and/or DSL.